# Variable in mkdir?

Tags: php, variables, mkdir

I want to create a subfolder inside mp3 with the name of $ts (the current timestamp) but php doesn't really allow me to do that.

This is my code:

```
$ts = time();
mkdir('\xampp\htdocs\mp3\$ts', 0777, true);
```

I have already tried:

```
$ts = time();
mkdir('\xampp\htdocs\mp3\'.$ts.'', 0777, true);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are escaping the `'` accidentally:

```
mkdir('\\xampp\\htdocs\\mp3\\'.$ts, 0777, true);
```

You can also use double quotes:

```
mkdir("\\xampp\\htdocs\\mp3\\{$ts}", 0777, true);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked out just fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, only in double quoted strings variables get [interpolated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing).

```
$a = 'abc';
$b = 'abc$a'; // actual value abc$a
$c = "abc$a"; // actual value abcabc
```

seconds, this does not seem to be the full path. please provide full path and use slash instead of backslash, since backslash is used as an escape sequence (and in your second example it just escapes the quote and the actual value would be \xampp\htdocs\mp3.$ts. if there was no parse error ;)

Answer (score 1):

simplest method i found:

```
$ts = time();
mkdir("\xampp\htdocs\mp3\$ts", 0777, true);
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try this:

```
mkdir("\xampp\htdocs\mp3\" . time() . "\", 0777, true);
```